# How to start a Runnable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I need from my Class that implements `Runnable` was opening my Java EE application 7 Spring MVC. I declare my class in the `servlet.xml`:

```
<beans:bean class="MyClass" scope="singleton">
</beans:bean>
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="MyClass" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

and this is my Class which has a `run()` method which is from all the X minute but it does not work. Why?

```
@Scope("singleton")
@Component
public class MyClass implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myClass.class);

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 10000)
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
        LOG.debug("IN");
    }
}
```

my servlet.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.dao" />

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources 
    directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="com.MyClass" scope="singleton">
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<task:annotation-driven />` to your `servlet.xml`

`<annotation-driven />` is not enough

detail doc is here
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

dont forget 
xmlns

```
<bean ....
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd"
```

## ex: replace your xml head

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    ">
```

Comment: @MaximeF paste your xml plz, `task:annotation-driven` not something else xx:annotation-driven

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'task:annotation-driven'.
 - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'task:annotation-driven' of schema namespace 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/
  spring-task-3.0.xsd'

Comment: @MaximeF wrong xml, move http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  to xsi:schemaLocation= http://www.springframework.org/schema/task ...xsd

Comment: Now I have an error with the xsi  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc

Comment: Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" was already specified for element "beans:beans".

Comment: @MaximeF copy mine and you should pay time to understand how such thing works

Answer (score 0):

for bean MyClass add full package id="myClass" class ="your.package.name.MyClass". And all those annotations need be scanned in order to be detected and try adding @Component("myClass")